# JavaParser exception 'Lexical error' raised when a file containing German umlauts (äöüß) is parsed

Tags: java, utf-8, character-encoding, diacritics

I'm parsing a lot of .java-files with the latest [JavaParser](http://code.google.com/p/javaparser/).

Files are parsed like this:

```
in = new FileInputStream(file);
cu = JavaParser.parse(in);
```

The following exception is raised as soon as one of the source-files contains a German umlaut (ä,ö,ü,ß) (they only appear in the comments of the .java-file)

> Exception in thread "main" japa.parser.TokenMgrError: Lexical error at line 82, column 17.  Encountered: "\ufffd" (65533), after : ""

What can I do to fix this problem. I can't change all source-files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an overload on `JavaParser.parse()` that takes an encoding. Depending on your file encoding, try this;

```
cu = JavaParser.parse(in, "ISO8859_1");
```

or this

```
cu = JavaParser.parse(in, "UTF8");
```

All supported encodings are listed [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/intl/encoding.doc.html).

Comment: Both encodings couldn't fix my problem.

Comment: @Hedge Does it give the same or another error message? A bit hard to guess what encoding is used, but if JavaParser uses NIO, it may need to be written `ISO-8859-1` instead. If that does not work, try switching UltraEdit to hex mode and post how one or a couple of the letters are encoded in hex. That will make it fairly easy to find the correct encoding.

Comment: I tried UTF8,UTF-8, ISO-8859-1 and SO8859_1. The hex-number for 'ü' is FC

Comment: @Hedge Definitely iso-8859-1 or iso-8859-15 encoding then (they only differ on the € sign if I remember correctly) Now if Java had constants for the encoding names instead of strings you have to figure out every time, it'd be easy...

Comment: You were right, both encodings work. My problem was that I forgot that the parse-command is executed in four different locations *facepalm*

Comment: It’s not just the € sign, actually. ISO-8859-15 differs from ISO-8859-1 in precisely 8 places:
A4 ⇒ U+20AC € `EURO SIGN`;
A6 ⇒ U+0160 Š `LATIN CAPITAL LETTER S WITH CARON`;
A8 ⇒ U+0161 š `LATIN SMALL LETTER S WITH CARON`;
B4 ⇒ U+017D Ž `LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Z WITH CARON`;
B8 ⇒ U+017E ž `LATIN SMALL LETTER Z WITH CARON`;
BC ⇒ U+0152 Œ `LATIN CAPITAL LIGATURE OE`;
BD ⇒ U+0153 œ `LATIN SMALL LIGATURE OE`; and
BE ⇒ U+0178 Ÿ `LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Y WITH DIAERESIS`.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are you just need to specify the right encoding:

```
cu = JavaParser.parse(in, "utf-8");
```

... or whatever your actual encoding is.

Comment: That sadly doesn't fix the problem. UltraEdit shows the encoding as UNIX.

Comment: @Hedge If it does not show UNIX-UTF8 (or possibly UTF8-UNIX, it's been a while since I used UltraEdit) as encoding in the toolbar, it's most likely encoded in iso-8859-1 or iso-8859-15.

Comment: @Hedge: Well where did you get the source code from? There's no such encoding as "UNIX" - that's probably just indicating the line endings really.

Comment: I tried both for io and nio-API. They didn't work. Its probably just regular ASCII-code. The source-code comes straight from my company's version control system. Its ClearCase but I can't tell you on what kind of machines it runs. Could be UNIX or z/OS.

Comment: @Hedge: It's definitely not ASCII if it contains umlauts... you should ask one of your colleagues or a system adminstrator which encoding is being used.